# When can't a real definite integral be evaluated using contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Some older complex analysis textbooks state that  $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}} \ dx$ can't be evaluated using contour integration.

But that's now known not to be true, which makes me  wonder if you can ever definitively state that a particular real definite integral can't be evaluated using contour integration.

**Edit:** (t.b.) a famous instance of the above claim is in Watson, *[Complex Integration and Cauchy's theorem](http://archive.org/stream/complexintegrati00wats#page/78/mode/2up)* (1914), page 79:

[image: Watson's claim]

Comment: Could you add references for your statements? E.g., which older complex analysis textbooks do state this where?

Comment: @Thomas: see edit.

Comment: How about considering an integral on the real line that is so bizarre that it cannot be a profile of some holomorphic function?

Comment: @sos440 Would you give an example? I'd vote for that answer. Would something like $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-1/x^2}\cdot e^{-x^2}\,dx$ work?

Comment: $\int_0^1|\sin(1/x)|dx$?

Comment: While I find this question very interesting, I have to note that the formulation in the quoted text is quite prudent. It does circumvent the statement that the example cannot be evaluated.

Comment: Huh, how do we compute $\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ with contour integration?

Comment: @Yrogirg: (late answer...) quite simply by taking as contour the first quarter of the circle : $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^2\,dx+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}2} e^{2i\phi}ie^{i\phi}\,d\phi +\int_1^0 (ix)^2 i\,dx=0\ $ that becomes $\ \displaystyle (1+i)\int_0^1 x^2\,dx=\frac {1+i}3 $.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni You can answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156372/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-int-01-xn-dx-by-contour-integration

Comment: @Yrogirg: I did just that (I had to change a bit the principle of the fixed angle $\frac {\pi}2$ to avoid the problems for odd $n$). I hope you'll like it!

Answer (score 4):

There are such functions. For example, anything with infinitely many discontinuities. Take the Dirichlet function as an example; it is Lebesgue integrable, but one could not integrate it using the method of residues, which requires that there are only finitely many poles of the function on the real line.