# Evaluating definite integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

This question came up when I was reading through this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis).

Are there definite integrals which *cannot* be computed using *any* real analysis techniques but are amenable using *only* complex analysis techniques?

If not, is there any reason to believe that if a definite integral can be evaluated using a complex analysis technique, then there *must* exist a way to compute the same definite integral using only real analysis techniques?

---

**EDIT**

Started a bounty for this question.

Comment: What is an example of a complex analysis technique that cannot be considered (a disguised instance of) a real analysis technique?

Comment: For instance, using Cauchy integral formula, method of residues, etc.

Comment: So, now you need a rigorous definition of "real analysis method" that excludes these things.  I don't know of one.

Comment: Interesting question! The challenge would be to define "real analysis technique" in a way that allows proof of existence of such a definite integral.

Comment: Extract : "One time I boasted, "I can do by other methods any integral anybody else needs contour 
integration to do." 
So Paul puts up this tremendous damn integral he had obtained by starting out with a complex 
function that he knew the answer to, taking out the real part of it and leaving only the complex part. 
He had unwrapped it so it was only possible by contour integration! He was always deflating me 
like that. He was a very smart fellow." Richard Feynman in "Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!"

Comment: This does not seem like a well-posed question.

Comment: There are certainly real integrals which are much more easily computed with contour integration in the complex plane (for example, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}$) but as the other comments suggest, I'm not sure that this methodology precludes being a technique of "real analysis."

Comment: An opposite question may be of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126655/when-a-real-valued-integral-cant-be-evaluated-using-contour-integration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are so many such definite integrals that cannot be solved by real analysis techniques, such as

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dx}{1+x^n}.$$

By the Cauchy's integral formula, we can compute it simply.

Comment: This integral can be evaluated with the beta function. We don't need complex analysis.